# java jre installer goes into "stealth mode"

Tags: windows-7, windows, java, installer, jre

Lenovo T61 running Windows 7 Prof.  No java installed as per Control Panel>Programs, javare, Total Uninstaller, etc.  Typing "java" at the CLI returns "not recognized". No java in c:\program files. No tell tail registry entries that I can find.

I have tried jre-7-windows-i586.exe, jre-7-windows-i586-iftw.exe, and chromeinstall-7u67.exe.  I get the sanity check and the exe shows to be running, but nothing shows on the desktop.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Clarification: the exe shows to be running because it is in the Task Manager Process List.

Comment: Try following http://www.java.com/en/download/help/log_files.xml to generate a log file and post it.

Comment: I followed the instructions.  The only file that showed up in %TEMP% was jusched.log.  The contents of the file are;  
Thu Oct 09 13:25:17 2014
:: No Old AU Version found